# How To Animate UIView Frame with ViewWillLayoutSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have created two UIViews Programmatically and set its frame in ViewWillLayoutSubview function, Now I want to create a swapping animation so that each view swap each others position with animation on a click. For getting this animation I have to interchange its frame inside an animation but at the same time ViewWillLayoutSubview get called which sets frame to initial position.

How can I get my UIViews to be swapped with animation using ViewWillLayoutSubview?

I am not using any type of constraint or xib or storyboard. Whole screen is designed programatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    if(Once)
   {
       // create 2 views here

      once = NO;
   }

}
```

put this code in button click

```
CGRect view2Frame = self.view2.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
    //code with animation


      self.view2.frame = self.view1.frame;

      self.view1.frame = view2Frame;


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //code for completion
}];
```

Comment: what should I write in UIview Animation block?